# Can TCP/IP Server Accept a Connection Which is Being Forwarded by the ROunter

Tags: java, tcp

I have a fixed IP connection.
I am working on a project which will allow users to connect with my computer using a TCP/IP connection.
I am currently setting up the server on my machine (192.168.1.2) with port 69795.
My question is, if I forward all the requests made for the port to my machine, will the users be able to contact with the server?
I am sorry if my question is not clear.

Comment: Yes, this is a very common setup.

Comment: Yes, just try it. Though this is not a programming question, but more of a network/firewall/router configuration problem. You might have better luck at serverfault.com

Comment: Also, don't post your IP online. It's just a bad practice from a security standpoint, especially when you're developing a server on the same forwarded port. It's like saying, "Hey, I'm changing the locks at my address: 123 My Address, State/Zip. Am I doing this right?"

Comment: Thanks. Deleted that comment

Comment: No, because nothing will listen on port 69795.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, but generally the answer is yes.

The things that might make the answer change from yes to no that you can influence:

1. Your server doesn't have a program ready to accept the connection on the correct port on 192.168.1.2
2. Your server has a firewall that discards the packets (parts of the connection) on the desired port on 192.168.1.2
3. The router is not configured to allow packets from the public networks to route to your server
4. The server doesn't know how to send the reply packets back to the router.
5. The server's program that responds is misconfigured or misbehaving.

There are also elements that you cannot control (but they thankfully are not often problems)

1. Someone else's router is misconfigured.
2. Someone else's computer is running a restrictive or misconfigured firewall or proxy.
3. Someone else has a client that is misconfigured or malfunctioning.

I suggest if you look into the Ciso CENT certification learning materials to get the basics of networking if you care to understand how some of this stuff works; but, you can easily configure your system to work without such understanding.  If your setup misbehaves, often you can even fix it without full understanding.  However, a good understanding of the details help greatly when something goes wrong.